# Is it possible to upload a file by url to cloud storage on app engine without writing to disk?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

To upload a file from url to a cloud storage system, usually it is required to download that file on a server, and then upload it to the cloud storage.

For large files, it may be required to write the file on disk instead of memory. Since app engine does not support writing on disks, are there any other options for doing this on app engine?

I understand that managed vm is an option, but I'm trying to make sure that it's definitely not possible to do this on classic app engine.

Comment: you can copy from one stream to another, why you want to write to a disk?

Comment: Sure, but does app engine client libraries support this? Is it possible to pipe `urlfetch` to `cloudstorage` python packages for streaming? Could you provide a code sample as an answer?

Comment: oh, I don't know about python libs, but java libs have streams and everything. you could probably make a java module for this task

Answer (score 2):

To overcome the lack of local disk on GAE you can:

- use the [blobstore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Uploading_a_Blob)
- better yet, use directly the cloud storage: [Upload images/video to google cloud storage using Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364878/upload-images-video-to-google-cloud-storage-using-google-app-engine?rq=1), [Sending images to google cloud storage using google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237747/sending-images-to-google-cloud-storage-using-google-app-engine).

To download the files to GAE you could use the [URL service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/). But there are 2 limitations to keep an eye on:

- the file download duration causing DeadlineExceededErrors in url fetching, you could bump it to 10 min on background tasks, see [App Engine Python UrlFetch.set_default_fetch_deadline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953729/app-engine-python-urlfetch-set-default-fetch-deadline)
- the [max URL fetch response size of 32M](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/#Python_Quotas_and_limits), for which [the Sockets service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/) appears to be a workaround (paid apps only): see [GAE - urlfetch multipart post not working with large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101854/gae-urlfetch-multipart-post-not-working-with-large-files)

If the server offering the downloads supports multi-part downloads it *might* be possible to get a solution working for any file sizes with this info.

Note: this is just theoretical, I've only thought about this, I didn't actually tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You can generate an upload URL (*using Cloud Storage API*) and provide it to a client that should use it in a POST request.

Here is [docs for PHP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload) but this approach should be working for Python as well.

Here is an example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python

Comment: How can this be used to stream a file from a url to the cloud storage upload url?

Comment: It was not too clear from your question you are fetching/downloading file. I was thinking about situation when you want a user or 3d party app to upload a file. In you case my answer is not relevant.